# Screenleap returning NULL in php

Tags: php, api, curl, broadcast, screensharing

I have created developer account in screenleap and trying to integrate screenleap API into my application, but when I am trying sample request code generated by screenleap it is giving me NULL.

**How to test sample request in php?**

```
    $url = 'https://api.screenleap.com/v2/screen-shares';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authtoken:my_authtoken'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'accountid=my_accountid');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($data,true);
    var_dump($json);
```

Comment: What do you get if you echo `$data`? Feeding `json_decode()` incorrect data will return NULL.

Comment: A successful request will return a response with 200 status code and a JSON object

Comment: Can you give an example of that JSON response?

Comment: i followed: https://www.screenleap.com/api/presenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your system defaults aren't working for the SSL certificate verification.

You can try turning off the verification with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If that works, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.